# Print string domain values with comma separation in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I have a domain I'd like to output with commas. In Python I can use the `string` **`.join()`** method, being fed by a `list` **`.sort()`**-ed product, but in Chapel I am not getting the right results.

```
var names = { "anze kopitar",
              "tyler toffoli",
              "drew doughty",
              "jeff carter",
              "tanner pearson"
               };

writeln( names );
writeln( names.sorted() );
writeln( ",".join( names ) );
writeln( ",".join( names.sorted() ) );
```

I'd like the last line to read

```
anze kopitar,drew doughty,jeff carter,tanner pearson,tyler toffoli
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chapel 1.16, `string.join` only supports varargs, tuples, and arrays as arguments. For now you will need to convert your domain to one of those types before joining:

```
var dom = {"apple", "orange", "carrot"};
var A = dom.sorted(); // 'A' is an array
const s = ",".join(A);
writeln(s);
```

The output is:

```
apple,carrot,orange
```

Comment: How complex will be to "inline" a non-DUP method into the Chapel language? Given Brian typically works not with just a few hockey players, but rather with immense data-scales, the *"just"*-the-current-syntax-constraints motivated duplication will not be possible in all cases, where [SPACE] hard-limits do not permit any similar constraint workarounds. Thanks to add more light into this.

Comment: Are you wondering how difficult it would be to add a method/function that removes duplicates from something? I think it depends on what 'something' is. If it's an array, then I suppose one could perform an in-place sort and then walk the array looking for adjacent duplicates. I'm not familiar with the optimal algorithm for this problem, but I'm not aware of anything specific to Chapel that would overly complicate things.

Comment: Negative, Sir. The point was to completely avoid a dumb-DUP step of `var A = dom.sorted(); // 'A' is an array` and get the language convert the non-DUP-ed data "on-the-fly" rather than statically duplicating their representation in [SPACE] just to become able to move to the next step to process and finally assign `aStringSEPARATOR.join( A );`.

Comment: That sounds rather tricky to me. What patterns would trigger this non-DUP behavior? What types would it operate on? To have the compiler automatically insert this kind of operation seems complicated and hopefully unnecessary in the future. I think better behavior would be for `join` to accept any iterable thing, so one could write `sep.join(dom.sorted())`.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I tried to formulate when trying to ask **how complex it would be to extend the Chapel language for doing this** ( and principally avoid the costs of double allocated `[SPACE]`-footprint present in the interim workaround proposed in your current-syntax motivated answer ).